# Как хранить массив в поле БД

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

Добрый день.

Есть 2 таблицы: Рецепт и Ингредиент.

- В таблице "Рецепт" есть поля:
  ReceptID,Title,
  IngridientID
- В таблице "Ингридиент" есть поля:
  IngridientID,
  Title

Вопрос заключается в том, как мне хранить несколько ингредиентов в одном рецепте?
В будущем планируется поиск рецепта по ингредиентам.

Есть у меня пару вариантов как это реализовать:

1. Хранить как-то в таблице Рецептов в поле массив ингредиентов.
2. Добавить еще одну таблицу связывающую - "IngidientInRecept", которая содержит ReceptID и IngridientID.

Подскажите каким лучше способом это сделать?
Какой более правильный и быстрее будет работать.

Comment: с доп таблицей естественно. хоть какую нибудь книжку то по БД прочитайте, прежде чем начинать что-либо делать. _зы: и называете первичные ключи просто `id` не надо в них добавлять название таблиц, это к внешним ключам добавляется_

Comment: Способ с дополнительной таблицей полностью правильный. Так оно, в общем-то, и делается. А хранить в поле массив - это полный треш, так не надо.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Буду пробовать..

Comment: Можите хранить рецепт в поле типа xml или json, если база данных имеет такие и умеет выполнять запросы по таким данным

Answer (score 1):

С данной связью разобрался.

```
public class Recept
{
public int Id { get; set }
public string Title { get; set; } 

public List<Ingridient> Inridients { get; set; }
}

public class Ingridient
{
public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title { get; set; }

public List<Recept> Recepts { get; set; }
}
```

После чего создается таблица: InridientRecepts c Id рецепта и Id ингредиента.

Но, как я понимаю в эту созданную связывающую таблицу добавлять поля нельзя. Мне бы хотелось еще хранить "Вес\Количество ингредиента(ов)".

И тут я начинаю путаться. Т.е. Нужно создать самому третью таблицу с нужными мне полями, включающую Id рецепта и ингредиента. Подсмотрел небольшой пример с професорвэба (еще не пробовал).

```
public class Recept
{
.....
public virtual  List<IngridientInRecept> IngridientInRecepts
}

public class Ingridient
{
.....
public virtual  List<IngridientInRecept> IngridientInRecepts
}

public class IngridientInRecept
{
[Key, ForeignKey("Recept")]
public int ReceptId { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("Ingridient")]
public int IngridientId { get; set; }

public int Quantity { get; set; }

public Recept Recept { get; set; }
public Ingridient Ingridient { get; set; }
}
```

С данным методом нужно указать явный список сортировки - добавить это можно

```
[Column(IngridientInRecept = 0)]
[Column(IngridientInRecept = 1)]
```

К первым двум полям Id рецепта и ингредиента в таблице IngridientInRecept.

И это вроде как должно сработать.

При добавлении нового рецепта выводим:

```
Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Ingridients.Id, selectList, «choose»)
```

Далее мы выбрали из списка нужные нам ингредиенты.

А вот как добавить вес\количество к выбранным ингредиентам?
Думал про какую-нибудь динамическую форму... но пока что вообще не понимаю как это реализовать.. 
Подскажите советом..

Извиняюсь, что отошёл немного от первоначальной темы.
Спасибо.

Comment: Ответу плюс, всё правильно разобрались. А отдельный вопрос про форму нужно задавать отдельным топиком.

Answer (score 0):

> В будущем планируется поиск рецепта по ингредиентам

В первом случае придётся перебирать все значения из таблицы рецептов, что может долго выполняться, если рецептов много. Во втором случае можно выполнять запросы вроде `SELECT ReceptID FROM IngidientInRecept WHERE IngridientID = ... or IngridientID = ...` (или использовать JOIN с таблицей Рецепт и искать совпадения в поле `Title`) Если поле `IngridientID` проиндексировано, то такой запрос, очевидно, будет выполняться быстрее.